# Machinist vs FactoryGirl - pros and cons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot, machinist

I'm working with factory_girl, but looking at the machinist gem. Could you tell me please - what are the pros and cons of migrating to machinist? Have you compared those libs?

Comment: not a direct answer to your question, but you might also check out miniskirt: http://www.stephencelis.com/2010/01/11/miniskirt.html ... as a factory_girl user, I like how this simple lib approaches factories with better syntax and less weight.

Comment: machinist? factory girl? miniskirt? what kind of forum did I stumble into?

Comment: @DonalBoyle you could be impressed more if you will know that there is also a [factory_boy](https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy) :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Machinist](http://github.com/notahat/machinist) was actually heavily inspired by [factory_girl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), but varied because machinist's author wanted a different syntax.  Since then, factory_girl  added different syntax layers to simulate other factory libraries (including machinist's "blueprint" syntax).  In other words, both are extremely similar, just with a different default syntax.  Personally, I use factory_girl.

Answer (score 17):

Actually, Machinist has a big advantage over Factory Girl: it doesn't hit the DB for associated objects. Look here:

[Machinist vs Factory Girl: Machinist win!](http://metalelf0dev.blogspot.com/2011/06/machinist-vs-factory-girl-machinist-win.html)

Still not sure about how Machinist handles this, but anyhow it could be a huge performance boost for your test base.

Comment: Just noticed in [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures-revised) that you can use `FactoryGirl.build` if you don't want to hit the database. Probably a new feature.

Comment: FactoryGirl.build actually hists the database for associated objects. FactoryGirl.build_stubbed creates objects without hitting the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used machinist before, but I can say factory_girl is quite easy to use, extend and rip out any rails-centricness it has to be used in any type of project.