# Is there a good alternative to factory_girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

It doesn't really seem like factory_girl receives much attention these days. Is there a better alternative? I really like FG, but I need to know that they'll keep working on it.

Particularly the slow pace of factory_girl_rails is annoying.

Comment: What do you need from factory_girl that it doesn't already provide?

Comment: I don't know if by "slow pace" OP was referring to how long it takes to load FG compared to fixtures.  That's certainly something I find annoying, though.  I can't just run rake:tasks and get a 2 second result, so I have to be more careful about making small changes and testing them.

Answer (score 10):

I personally prefer [Fabrication](https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication), but that's because it supports a few different ORMs and I use Mongoid. Also, it's been pretty fast in the tests I run.

Answer (score 3):

I know Machinist but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131357/machinist-vs-factorygirl-pros-and-cons), it doesn't really differ from Factory Girl.

Answer (score 3):

I like: https://github.com/ginty/cranky

Much simpler so it never breaks, doesn't need a -rails gem and works with any ORM.